# MATLAB won't read time field from database

Tags: sql, database, matlab, date

I'm having some problems importing a time variable from my database into MATLAB. I think the problem might have something to do with the format of the time parameter which is:

HH:MM:SS.MS

Example:

00:04:13.46

H = Hour, M = Minute, S = Second, MS = Millisecond.

When I use dexplore or querybuilder MATLAB doesn't seem to process the fact there is a time field here, instead just returning a [ ]. I think this may be something to do with the format of the time field.

My current code looks like this:

```
%Set preferences with setdbprefs.
setdbprefs('DataReturnFormat', 'structure');
setdbprefs('NullNumberRead', 'NaN');
setdbprefs('NullStringRead', 'null');

%Make connection to database.  Note that the password has been omitted.
%Using ODBC driver.
conn = database('DATABASE', '', '');

%Read data from database.
curs = exec(conn, ['SELECT  ARDAT.Date'...
    ' , ARDAT.Time'...
    ' FROM  DATABASE.dbo.ARDAT ']);
curs = fetch(curs);
close(curs);

%Assign data to output variable
data = curs.Data;

%Close database connection.
close(conn);

%Clear variables
clear curs conn
```

Is there a particular way I can force MATLAB to read the Time field as a string instead? Then I can just post process the data to fix it.

Comment: Use SQL-Syntax to convert the time to a string directly in the request to the database.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to SQL, how exactly would I do that?

Comment: CAST(ARDAT.Time AS VARCHAR(11))

Comment: Thanks for help your help! The variable is now converted to a string, but it's displaying as 00:04AM, is there anyway to force it stay in the same format and not convert?

Comment: Take a look at this link.
http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

That should help!!